# Building QGIS master on Windows 7

Tags: qgis, visual-studio, windows-7, debugging, compile

I'm trying to build a debug version of QGIS on windows env for this I'm using the bat file package-nightly, I followed all steps presents in INSTALL file but without success.

When I executed the bat file I received this error:

`-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/renan.b/QGIS/ms-windows/osgeo4w/build-qgis-dev-x86
CLEAN: 29/06/2017 14:36:16,58
Cleaning... 10 files.
ALL_BUILD: 29/06/2017 14:36:17,13
[1/4225] Building CXX object src\native\CMakeFiles\qgis_native.dir\qgsnative.cpp.obj
FAILED: src/native/CMakeFiles/qgis_native.dir/qgsnative.cpp.obj
C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1.0\VC\bin\cl.exe   /nologo /TP -DENABLE_TESTS -DNOMINMAX -DQGISDEBUG=1 -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0 -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DWI
TH_BINDINGS -DWITH_QTWEBKIT -D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -Dqgis_native_EXPORTS -I. -I..\..\..\src\native -
Isrc\native /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc -DSPATIALITE_VERSION_GE_4_0_0 -DSPATIALITE_VERSION_G_4_1_1 -DSPATIALITE_HAS_INIT_EX  /wd4100  /wd4127  /w
d4190  /wd4231  /wd4244  /wd4251  /wd4275  /wd4505  /wd4510  /wd4512  /wd4610  /wd4706  /wd4800  /MD /ZI /MP /Od /D NDEBUG /D QGISDEBUG -DQGISDEBUG=1
/showIncludes /Fosrc\native\CMakeFiles\qgis_native.dir\qgsnative.cpp.obj /Fdsrc\native\CMakeFiles\qgis_native.dir\ -c C:\Users\renan.b\QGIS\src\native
\qgsnative.cpp
c:\users\renan.b\qgis\src\native\qgsnative.h(34) : error C2065: 'default' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\renan.b\qgis\src\native\qgsnative.h(34) : error C2258: illegal pure syntax, must be '= 0'
[2/4225] Generating qgscontexthelp_texts.cpp
Files "C:/Users/renan.b/QGIS/ms-windows/osgeo4w/build-qgis-dev-x86/src/core/qgscontexthelp_texts.cpp.temp" to "C:/Users/renan.b/QGIS/ms-windows/osgeo4
w/build-qgis-dev-x86/src/core/qgscontexthelp_texts.cpp" are different.
[3/4225] Generating qgsexpression_texts.cpp
Files "C:/Users/renan.b/QGIS/ms-windows/osgeo4w/build-qgis-dev-x86/src/core/qgsexpression_texts.cpp.temp" to "C:/Users/renan.b/QGIS/ms-windows/osgeo4w
/build-qgis-dev-x86/src/core/qgsexpression_texts.cpp" are different.
[6/4225] Generating flex_qgsexpressionlexer.cpp
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
[5/4220] Building CXX object src\native\CMakeFiles\qgis_native.dir\qgsnative.cpp.obj
FAILED: src/native/CMakeFiles/qgis_native.dir/qgsnative.cpp.obj
C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1.0\VC\bin\cl.exe   /nologo /TP -DENABLE_TESTS -DNOMINMAX -DQGISDEBUG=1 -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0 -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DWI
TH_BINDINGS -DWITH_QTWEBKIT -D_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_WARNINGS -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -Dqgis_native_EXPORTS -I. -I..\..\..\src\native -
Isrc\native /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc -DSPATIALITE_VERSION_GE_4_0_0 -DSPATIALITE_VERSION_G_4_1_1 -DSPATIALITE_HAS_INIT_EX  /wd4100  /wd4127  /w
d4190  /wd4231  /wd4244  /wd4251  /wd4275  /wd4505  /wd4510  /wd4512  /wd4610  /wd4706  /wd4800  /MD /ZI /MP /Od /D NDEBUG /D QGISDEBUG -DQGISDEBUG=1
/showIncludes /Fosrc\native\CMakeFiles\qgis_native.dir\qgsnative.cpp.obj /Fdsrc\native\CMakeFiles\qgis_native.dir\ -c C:\Users\renan.b\QGIS\src\native
\qgsnative.cpp
c:\users\renan.b\qgis\src\native\qgsnative.h(34) : error C2065: 'default' : undeclared identifier
c:\users\renan.b\qgis\src\native\qgsnative.h(34) : error C2258: illegal pure syntax, must be '= 0'
[10/4220] Generating moc_qgsdataitem.cpp
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
build failed twice
BUILD ERROR 1: 29/06/2017 14:36:20,63
FINISHED: 29/06/2017 14:36:20,63`

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score -1):

windows env add path

---

PYTHONHOME

Install Dir\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27

PYTHONPATH

Install Dir\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\lib;
Install Dir\OSGeo4W64\bin;